# Removing '\xa0' character from a multidimensional list

Tags: python, list, ascii

Consider a following list:
(I forgot to mention that my list also has numbers, int-s)

```
foo_list = [['foo', 100], ['\xa0foo', 200], ['foo\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0', 300], ['foo', 400]]
```

I've tried cleaning the list with the following function I found on SO when I was googling:

```
def remove_from_list(l, x):
  new_list = [li.replace(x, u'') for li in l]
  return new_list

foo_list_clean = remove_from_list(foo_list, u'\xa0')
```

This obviously gives me:
(a new error)

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Is it because it's a list of lists? How could I modify the code so that it'd work and remove the '`\xa0`' character.

My expected output would be a new list with cleaned values from `foo_list`.

Comment: Are your strings *bytestrings* or *unicode*?

Comment: And only the first element is a string?

Comment: The problem changed a bit, because the list also has numbers. I forgot to mention that in the original post.

Comment: Yes, only the fist element is a string.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `str.strip()` on the first element, leaving the rest of the inner list intact:

```
[[inner[0].strip('\xa0')] + inner[1:] for inner in foo_list]
```

`\xa0` is a non-breaking space, and provided your values are Unicode strings these will be stripped of without specifying an argument. Your sample input consists of *bytestrings* so I used an explicit strip:

```
>>> foo_list = [['foo', 100], ['\xa0foo', 200], ['foo\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0', 300], ['foo', 400]]
>>> [[inner[0].strip('\xa0')] + inner[1:] for inner in foo_list]
[['foo', 100], ['foo', 200], ['foo', 300], ['foo', 400]]
```

Your own approach would work fine too, but you need to use the function on *slices of each nested list*:

```
foo_list_clean = [remove_from_list(inner[:1], u'\xa0') + inner[1:] for inner in foo_list_clean]
```

However, using `str.replace()` is not needed unless you have those `\xa0` non-breaking spaces *in between words*; your sample only contains them at the starts and ends.

Note that if *some* elements are integers and others are strings, you'll have to do some duck typing:

```
[[s.strip('\xa0') if hasattr(s, 'strip') else s for s in inner]
 for inner in foo_list]
```

Note that if your inputs are instead `unicode` objects, you'll have to use a matching `u'\xa0'` string to strip with! Alternatively, just use `unicode.strip()` without arguments to remove *all* whitespace from the start and end (as `\xa0` is [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00A0) and is considered whitespace):

```
>>> foo_list = [[u'foo', 100], [u'\xa0foo', 200], [u'foo\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0', 300], [u'foo', 400]]
>>> [[inner[0].strip()] + inner[1:] for inner in foo_list]
[[u'foo', 100], [u'foo', 200], [u'foo', 300], [u'foo', 400]]
```

Comment: For some reason, I'm unable to get the desired result. Then again, if I used code that was provided by another poster (he/she deleted it for some reason) it works: `foo_list_clean = [[item.replace(u'\xa0', '') if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in items] for items in foo_list]`

Comment: @user3596479: Define *doesn't work* here. Do you mean you have `\xa0` *in the middle*, or that all your strings are really unicode strings and using `'\xa0'` without the `u` prefix (making them bytestrings) is causing decoding / encoding issues, or what?

Comment: @user3596479: note that the answer works for the *sample data* you posted. If that's not representative of your actual data, can you please update that?